# Many conditions depends on IF clause within WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

How can I implement a `WHERE` clause that depends on one `@value` condition, like that pseudocode below:

```
Select * from table
WHERE
IF(@value is not null) 
    Id > 10 and Name = 'example' and Address is not null and ... etc
ELSE 
    Email is not null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen you can't use an `if` like that, but you can create the desired behavior using the `and` and `or` logical operators:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  (@value IS NOT NULL AND 
        id > 10 AND 
        name = 'example' AND 
        address IS NOT NULL AND -- etc...) OR
       (@value IS NULL AND email IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: @value is not name of column. It is a variable depends on.

Comment: @kenzolek Assuming it's passed into your function, you can still use it in this fashion

Comment: This will include records with email is not null even when @value is not null, in case when, for example, name is not "example"

Comment: Record with `id: 9, email: "email@dot.com"` will be returned when @value is not null - which is not what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

You want return records with `email` is not null only when `@value` is `null`.
You need to specify "precondition" for both "branches" of "if .. else" in your example.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE (@value IS NOT NULL AND Id > 10 AND ....)
    OR (@value IS NULL AND Email IS NOT NULL)
```